# Configure Haskell SDK for the Haskell IntelliJ plug-in

Tags: haskell, intellij-idea, sdk, ghc

I'm trying to start `Tools -> Start Haskell REPL`, but I'm getting this error:

> Error: Cannot run program "/usr/lib/ghc-7.8.4/bin/ghci" (in directory ...): error=2, No such file or directory

Which looks legitimate, as `ghci` resides elsewhere:

```
$ locate ghci
/usr/bin/ghci
/usr/bin/ghci-7.8.4
/usr/lib/ghc-7.8.4/ghci-usage.txt
...
```

(Haskell installed from the dedicated repository, Archlinux). Unfortunately, I've been given no leeway concerning Haskell SDK location.

> `Project Structure -> Project SDK -> GHC -> Select Home Directory for GHC`

forces `/usr/lib/ghc-7.8.4` choice on me.

Comment: I've made it work by (1) creating a link **$ ln -s /usr/bin/ghci /usr/lib/ghc-7.8.4/bin/ghci** (2) placing GHC SDK location at **/usr** (https://github.com/Atsky/haskell-idea-plugin/issues/58). This looks inelegant, to say the least.

Answer (score -1):

install Haskell stack.

in case you run on Ubuntu do:

curl -sSL https://get.haskellstack.org/ | sh

On my System Stack has been installed to: /usr/local/bin/stack

Comment: mv /usr/lib/ghc/bin/ghc /usr/lib/ghc/bin/ghc_old

Comment: ln -s /opt/ghc/7.10.3/bin/ghc /usr/lib/ghc/bin/ghc